# im getting a bad request 400 when I try to send some registration information to the server Cannot deserialize instance of out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: javascript, json, jersey

im still learning how to do this, and its my first time of full stack, im getting a an error 400 bad request when I try to parse json to the server and I don't know why, can you help me understand

[my javascript code trying to communicate with server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKcd0.png)

[400 bad request error on the console when I click register button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUhPJ.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images as code. Copy and paste the code here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to serialize the body data you are sending to the server with json stringify or another tool per web standards. Posting your server logic might help too.

here is the fetch documentation to stringify json before sending to the server to be read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: thanks a lot its solved, used stringily on the body and it worked.